# Prove that $0< \sum_{k=1}^{n}g(k)/k-2n/3 < 2/3$

Tags: number-theory

How to prove  that for all positive integers $n$
$$0< \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{g(k)}{k}-\frac{2n}{3}<\frac{2}{3}$$
where $g(k)$ denotes the greatest odd divisor of $k$

Comment: Just a note (not a big deal, since it's easily corrected and I'm not sure whether it's written down in the rules somewhere): I think it's considered bad form to have "display style" (`$$ ... $$` or `\[ ... \]`) math in titles, since it takes up a lot of room on the front page.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at the problem yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $k/g(k)$ is the greatest power of $2$ dividing $k$.

Comment: I didn't understand the hint .

Comment: Add up the contributions of $g(k)/k=1,  1/2, 1/4, \ldots$, which are at most $(n+1)/2, (n+2)/8, (n+4)/16, \ldots$.  What do you get?